# Unable to load the PHP files other then index.php file from NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans

I am trying to run the other PHP files from my project folder that I am currently working on, I get this error while running it straight from NetBeans.

> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Otherwise, when I run the project from localhost it opens up the main page index.php perfectly.

Please advise on what I am missing.

The address that I am trying is:

http://localhost/evs/php342/project/process/process_signup.php

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. You are saying index loaded perfectly but the URL you pasted is not for index.php. Check the folder structure you have on localhost again, it might be linking issue.

Comment: yes the index file loaded perfectly <http://localhost/project/>
but other then that no luck! when i try to open  any other php file which is currently in use  this gives me an error which i have mentioned above.
php file's that i have tried to open up in browser but gives me error are
<http://localhost/evs/php342/project/models/WebUser.php>
<http://localhost/evs/php342/project/process/process_signup.php>

Answer (score 0):

I hope your project structure looks like this

[image: screenshot 1]

If you want to run `process_signup.php` as your default page while running the project from Netbeans you should configure the project.

In order to do that **Right Click** on your project and select **Properties**

Now select **Run Configuration**

In **Index File** text field select the `process_signup.php` file by using the **Browse** button right to the text field.

[image: screenshot 2]

Now you're good to go. **Right Click** on your project and select **Run**. After that Netbeans will launch your default page.